# Can we choose voltage polarity and current reference directions arbitrarily?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, capacitance, inductance

Suppose we have a simple $LC$ circuit as shown below.

[image]

I want to determine the following:

1. The charge function on capacitor plates at any given moment
2. The current at any given moment

For this, let us write the KVL in counterclockwise direction:

$$ \varphi_A -  \varphi_B + \varphi_B - \varphi_A = 0$$

Now suppose the voltage polarity and current direction references are chosen as shown. If I didn't guess the direction , I must simply get an answer with the "-" sign.

However, under this convention, we can write the KVL as:

$$-\frac{q}{C} + Lq'' = 0$$

The problem is that the solution to this is *exponential*, not even sinusoidal.

Why is that so?

**Does this mean that we can choose the voltage polarity and current direction references not arbitrarily, only according to some rules, such as passive and active sign conventions, in order to get a result that is consistent with physics?** If so, why?

Edit: I'll make my question as clear as vacuum. Bob D said in the comments:

> All I'm saying is you can choose any direction for the current, but
> when you do you need to have the potentials going from plus to minus
> in the direction of the chosen current if you are using conventional
> current (flow of positive charge).

**Why?**

Comment: In applying KVL once you’ve arbitrarily chosen  loop current directions,  voltage polarities  are plus to minus in the chosen direction of the current based on conventional current

Comment: That's passive sign convention. My question addresses the very reason this convention leads to the correct description of the physical phenomenon, yet my convention doesn't

Comment: @BobD also, suppose we connect a positive plate of a charged capacitor to a plate of an uncharged capacitor through an open switch, and the negative plate to the other uncharged capacitor plate through an inductor. Then close the switch. Due to charge conservation, we have that two positively charged plates are connected together, same for the negative ones. But current flows only in one direction, so it has to enter a negative plate of some capacitor. Assuming the current enters the positive plate of both capacitors will lead to a completely wrong equation.

Comment: So the passive sign convention doesn't work here. Or at least has some unspoken limitations and is more than just "current always enters through negative terminal and leaves through the other"

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to reverse BOTH the current direction and voltage polarity. That’s not my understanding of “passive sign convention.”

Comment: No, I'm not saying I use the passive sign convention. And I do not want to reverse anything. The problem is that I cannot know the actual current direction and voltage polarity beforehand, so I have to assume them and then solve the circuit. I do not reverse anything as I do not know the direction and polarity of any element. It is only after I solve the equations that I can see the direction

Comment: All I'm saying is you can choose any direction for the current, but when you do you need to have the potentials going from plus to minus  in the direction of the chosen current if you are using conventional current (flow of positive charge). If you don't then you're current is the flow of negative charge.

Comment: Current can flow out of positive capacitor's terminal as well as out of negative

Comment: It depends on a circuit and on a particular moment in time

Comment: At any given instant, current will flow out of the capacitor positive terminal and into the capacitor negative for conventional current (flow of positive charge).  Or the reverse if current is designated as the flow of negative charge. It can't go into or out of both terminals at the same time.

Comment: Current can go into - terminal and out of + terminal, or into + and out of -. Consider, for example, the situation I described above or simply charging or discharging a capacitor. And, actually, I used the exact current direction and terminal polarities you just suggested in my question, yet got an incorrect result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt to answer your question one last time, and be as explicit about everything as I can, I suggest you read carefully. You ask why this is true:

> All I'm saying is you can choose any direction for the current, but when you do you need to have the potentials going from plus to minus in the direction of the chosen current if you are using conventional current (flow of positive charge).

The answer is that the I-V relations (or Q-V in the case of capacitor, which is just the time integral of I-V) that are usually quoted/used assume the passive sign convention. If you don't stick with the passive sign convention, the relations will differ by a sign.

For any two-terminal device, to speak of a device voltage, we need to first choose a polarity: one terminal will be the "positive" terminal. If the device has terminals labeled $a$ and $b$, we can choose $a$ to be the "positive" terminal: all that this means is that we are defining the device voltage as $V=V_a - V_b$. We could just as well have picked $b$ as positive, which would mean $V = V_b - V_a$. The fact that we are calling $a$ the "positive" terminal doesn't mean $V_a \ge V_b$: all we mean by it is the definition $V = V_a - V_b$.

The passive sign convention (PSC) defines the device current as the current entering the positive terminal and exiting the device from the negative terminal. If $a$ is the positive terminal, the device current is the current entering terminal $a$. We can either choose a device polarity and then define the current to be consistent with PSC; or define the device current (e.g. define current as entering terminal $a$), and then choose the polarity to be consistent with PSC.

How does PSC define the capacitor charge $Q$? Suppose again $a$ is the positive terminal. Since current is defined as entering plate $a$, and since current is the rate at which charge flows into plate $a$, the capacitor charge is the charge on the positive plate of the capacitor (positive in the sense of polarity defined above). What is the capacitor Q-V relation? It is $Q = CV$. Why this and not $Q = -CV$? When $V > 0$, plate $a$ is at a higher voltage than $b$, which can only happen if $a$ has positive charge and $b$ has negative charge. You can verify that it also works when $V < 0$. The I-V relation is just the time derivative: $I = C\dot V$.

For an inductor, suppose for simplicity that the circuit contains no other inductor (this isn't a necessary assumption, and you can attempt the general case yourself or read it elsewhere). We write Faraday's law along any loop $C$ containing the inductor, oriented such that it "enters" the inductor at $a$:
$$\oint_C\vec E \cdot d\vec \ell=\int_{C_L}\vec E \cdot d\vec \ell + \int_{C_L'}\vec E \cdot d\vec \ell=-\dot \Phi=-L\dot I.$$
$C_L$ is segment of the loop within the conductor of the inductor, and $C_L'$ is the remainder of the loop, exiting the inductor at $b$ and entering at $a$. The first integral is zero because $\vec E = 0$ in an ideal inductor. The second integral concerns the region external to the inductor in which $\vec E$ is conservative, so it is $V_b - V_a$. We are left with
$$V = V_a - V_b = L\dot I.$$

Finally, your circuit. You have labeled the polarities on $C$ and $L$. You have defined $I$ to be counterclockwise around the loop. Note the current entering the positive terminal of $C$ is just $-I$. PSC requires that device currents be defined as entering the positive terminals, so $I_L = I = -I_C = -\dot Q_C$. This is all fine, the minus signs appear because the direction of $I$ isn't consistent with the capacitor polarity according to PSC.

Now we write KVL going counterclockwise around the loop:

$$-V_C + V_L = 0$$
$$-\frac{Q_C}{C} + L\dot I_L = 0$$
$$-\frac{Q_C}{C} - L\ddot Q_C = 0.$$

Comment: After thinking about my problem for a while, I came to the conclusion that my misunderstanding lies not in the passive sign convention, but in the definition of current in terms of charge function (which isn't actually so trivial, as current is defined rather as current density flux across a surface). Despite that, your answer helped a lot, tank you